# Agrupar valores mais próximos no PostgreSQL

Tags: python, sql, postgresql, pandas

Bom dia, pessoal.
Estou com uma dúvida referente a um agrupamento de dados no postgresql e gostaria de saber se podem me ajudar.

Eu tenho uma base de dados contendo uma tabela com horários de entrada em um estabelecimento, e outra tabela com horários de saída. Ambas tem em comum um número de ticket, que seria minha id. Preciso agrupar os valores de forma que eu consiga combinar os horários de entrada e saída mais próximos, de acordo com seu ticket. Isolando um ticket específico, obtive os seguintes dados:

```
entrada              ticket  
-------------------  --------  
2020-12-02 07:53:02       802  
2020-12-03 09:00:07       802  

saida                ticket  
-------------------  --------  
2020-12-02 16:42:12       802 
2020-12-03 17:22:21       802
```

Para tentar juntar estes dados, rodei o seguinte comando SQL:

```
select e.data as data_entrada, e.ticket as num_ticket, s.data as data_saida from entrada e
join saida s on e.ticket = s.ticket
group by data_entrada, data_saida, num_ticket
having e.ticket = '802' 
order by data_entrada, data_saida
```

Resultado obtido:

```
    data_entrada         num_ticket  data_saida
--  -------------------  --------    -------------------
 0  2020-12-02 07:53:02       802    2020-12-02 16:42:12
 1  2020-12-02 07:53:02       802    2020-12-03 17:22:21
 2  2020-12-03 09:00:07       802    2020-12-02 16:42:12
 3  2020-12-03 09:00:07       802    2020-12-03 17:22:21
```

Resultado esperado:

```
    data_entrada         num_ticket  data_saida
--  -------------------  --------    -------------------
 0  2020-12-02 07:53:02       802    2020-12-02 16:42:12
 3  2020-12-03 09:00:07       802    2020-12-03 17:22:21
```

Alguém teria uma proposta de solução, seja por SQL ou mesmo pelo Python? Aparentemente é simples, mas eu me perdi na query e não consegui ainda achar uma solução. Obrigado desde já.

Comment: Uma possibilidade é fazer um subselect a menor data de saída que seja maior ou igual à data de entrada para o ticket.

Comment: Acredito que baste fazer o `on e.ticket = s.ticket and e.data_entrada = s.data_entrada`

Comment: O mesmo `num_ticket` pode ter mais de uma `data_entrada` ou `data_saida` no mesmo dia? Se tiver, como fica o resultado esperado?

Comment: @Terry sim, pode. Nesse caso iria fazer a combinação com o registro ordenado mais próximo. Mas tendo uma solução para essa amostra eu posso tentar derivar depois o restante da solução.

Answer (score 1):

Acredito que o que você busca é possível usando o comando [`.merge_asof()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.merge_asof.html) no pandas. Ele permite que seja possível unir DataFrames por aproximação nos dados (no seu caso, por datas aproximadas). 
A [documentação](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.merge_asof.html) da função é bem completa e repleta de exemplos, mas caso fique alguma dúvida, você pode usar o campo de comentários e se possível complementarei a resposta.

```
#importando o pandas
import pandas as pd

#transformando as colunas para o tipo datetime
entrada['entrada'] = pd.to_datetime(entrada['entrada'])
saida['saida'] = pd.to_datetime(saida['saida'])

#aplicando o merge por aproximação pelas datas dentro de cada 'ticket'
df = pd.merge_asof(entrada, saida, 
          left_on = 'entrada', 
          right_on = 'saida',  
          by='ticket', 
          direction = 'forward')

df.head()
#saida
    entrada             ticket  saida
0   2020-12-02 07:53:02 802     2020-12-02 16:42:12
1   2020-12-03 09:00:07 802     2020-12-03 17:22:21
```

Comment: Perfeito, funcionou corretamente. Não conhecia o merge_asof, apenas o merge padrão mesmo. Muito obrigado.

Answer (score 0):

Com uso de um subselect:

```
SELECT e.data as data_entrada, 
       e.ticket as num_ticket, 
       (SELECT min(s.data) FROM saida s WHERE s.ticket = e.ticket AND s.data > e.data) as data_saida 
FROM entrada e 
WHERE e.ticket = '802'
ORDER BY data_entrada;
```

Comment: Com o uso de query também funcionou. Mais uma alternativa anotada aqui. Valeu mesmo, muito obrigado.